# CFSelenium breaks upon executing CLICK command

Tags: coldfusion, selenium-rc

I am creating testcases using CFSELENIUM and MXUNIT. Upon running, it fails upon executing the CLICK command here:

```
selenium.click("//button[@id='Submit']");
```

It throws the following error message.

> Application: The Response of the Selenium RC is invalid: ERROR:
>   Command execution failure. Please search the user group at
>   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users for error
>   details from the log window.  The error message is: Argument 1 of
>   EventTarget.dispatchEvent does not implement interface Event.

Please find below the code.

```
component extends="cfselenium.CFSeleniumTestCase" displayName="seleniumBase" {

    public void function beforeTests() {

        //your local host
        variables.browserUrl = "url";
        variables.browserCommand = "*firefox";

        super.beforeTests();
        selenium.setTimeout(50000);
        selenium.setSpeed( 500 );
    }

    public void function afterTests() {
        super.afterTests();
    }

    private void function logIn(){
        selenium.open(variables.browserUrl);
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");

        //your username
        variables.backofficeUserName = "test";
        selenium.type("id=UserName", variables.backofficeUserName);

        //your password
        variables.backofficePassword = "test";
        selenium.type("//input[@type = 'password']", variables.backofficePassword);

        selenium.click("//button[@id='Submit']");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Um.. before posting, did you do a search as suggested in the error message or check the [CFSelinium project](https://github.com/teamcfadvance/CFSelenium)? ;-)

A very brief search turns up several threads suggesting it is an issue resolved in later versions of Selinum, such as 2.42.2.

- [selenium.click() doesn't work: Argument 1 of EventTarget.dispatchEvent does not implement interface Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168227/selenium-click-doesnt-work-argument-1-of-eventtarget-dispatchevent-does-not)

The CFSelinium project also lists a bug fix that sounds a lot like your issue ..

- [Update to selenium-server 2.42.1; This fixes a problem with Firefox](https://github.com/teamcfadvance/CFSelenium/commit/065537d1f8360cff3622c53ab846cb520a45ade6)

Answer (score 0):

It may works in all browsers... try it...

```
selenium.click("//input[@id='Submit']");
```